# What's the speed limitation of Android on long running background services (Xamarin Forms)?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, xamarin.forms, android-service, background-service

A little background, I have been developing a Xamarin forms app that collects EEG data continuously generated from a BCI (brain computer interface) cap as a user performs brain activity (left arm or right arm movement, a user imagines lifting a left dumbbell or right dumbbell). This EEG data is then continuously classified using an ML algorithm to produce a control signal of -1 to 1.

This control signal will then be used to control the left or right movement of a character in a Unity3d game. Now the problem is, since they are two different apps, I will need a way to send the classifer's output from Xamarin Forms app to Unity3d app. I was looking into Android background services in Xamarin but I'm not entirely sure if a background service is capable enough to send data to the Unity app continuously at the rate of 4-8 ms (the rate at which data is classified). Is background service a good idea or are there any alternative ways to achieve this?

Other options is to re-create the Xamarin forms app from scratch in Unity so I don't have to handle the inter-process communication but again I don't think it's a good idea to use Unity for a non-game app dev.?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Edit: Sorry I didn't make it clear. Both the apps run on the same mobile device. I'm already using UDP and this will work if they are on two separate devices. But if they are on the same device, XF apps still need to continue running the classifier code and send the output to the unity game in a background service and I'm not sure if this is doable

Comment: You can use socket for this. TCP should be fine....

Comment: @Programmer please see the edit

Comment: Your edit doesn't change a thing in my comment. You can use TCP to do this. Note that I didn't say UDP. I said TCP. Create server on local device. Connect to local device.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to run the tcp server as a service so that it doesn't stop working once the app goes in the background?